# Correct try/catch usage

Tags: android, database, try-catch

Can someone please explain to me the proper usage of try/catch when accessing an Android database? Android Studio forces you to use it whenever you are opening a database for writing. I understanding the purpose of using it but my question is would it better do include all of my database work in the try clause like this?

```
try {
        db.open();
        db.delete(item);
        db.add(item);
        /////......
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

db.close()
```

Or is it better to use it like this?

```
try {
        db.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

db.delete(item);
db.add(item);
/////......

db.close()
```

Is there an important difference? Is one way more efficient or safer than the other?
Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: the first is better, if u try delete and it doesnt exist..error

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation and only use try / catch on methods that throw exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You use the catch block to actually catch exceptions which can be thrown from your code (during runtime). So every call which can throw an exception should be tried/catched, because it helps you differentiating, what went wrong with your code.
So: Wrap a try catch around every function call which can throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

in your second example, if your delete query is malformed, you won't know, the program will continue to run thinking it's been successful.

A try catch, tries something, then catches any errors which may arise.

Comment: I see that I wasn't being very smart in considering which of the 2 options was better. Thanks for the response!